# Reallocating SQL Server Image Space

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I recently removed a few gigabytes worth of data from my server running SQL Server 2005.  This data was of the 'Image' datatype.  After deleting the records, the PC has yet to show that that data has been actually freed.  I've tried DBCC CLEANTABLE and DBCC SHRINKFILE, and it's just not working.  I've googled this for a while, and I haven't come across a definite answer.  Has anyone else run into this situation before?  How did you solve it?

Thanks,
Aaron

Comment: Have you also tried shrinking the transaction log? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174524(v=sql.80).aspx

Comment: Yes, but the transaction logs are held on a separate disk drive, so it wouldn't have an effect on the space in the drive that we have all of our data in.  Sorry I forgot to mention that in my question.

Answer (score 0):

See: [DBCC SHRINKFILE and SHRINKDATABASE commands may not work because of sparsely populated text, ntext, or image columns](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-us;324432)

Comment: Looks like a very good article, but it applies to SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 7.  Do you know if this would apply to SQL Server 2005 as well?

Comment: @Aaron: I can't say for sure, but I've seen similar situations where I tried rebuilding clustered indexes, CLEANTABLE, etc. and the only thing that would work was copying the data into a brand new table.